# Как получить пользователя в консольной команде

Tags: php, yii2

Есть класс Accounts который наследуется от ActiveRecord. Когда в консольной команде пытаюсь сделать следующее
`$account = Accounts::findOne(["id" => 1]);`

в консоли выводит это:

```
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver' in F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:547

Stack trace:
0 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(861): yii\db\Connection->open()
1 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(848): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
2 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(219): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
3 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(894): yii\db\Command->prepare(true)
4 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(376): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetch', NULL)
5 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(247): yii\db\Command->queryOne()
6 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(290): yii\db\Query->one(NULL)
7 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php(107): yii\db\ActiveQuery->one()
8 F:\wamp\www\blog\commands\RbacController.php(36): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::findOne(Array)
9 [internal function]: app\commands\RbacController->actionTest()
10 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
11 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
12 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(119): yii\base\Controller->runAction('test', Array)
13 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(454): yii\console\Controller->runAction('test', Array)
14 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(176): yii\base\Module->runAction('rbac/test', Array)
15 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(143): yii\console\Application->runAction('rbac/test', Array)
16 F:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
17 F:\wamp\www\blog\yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()
18 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас вероятно не настроено подключение к базе данных для консольных команд. [Документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html#configuration)